# Using an if/else statement when checking items in lists of varying lengths

Tags: python

I have a list that will currently either have 1 or 2 items. If the item 2('b') in the list exists, I want to see if it exists in another list. If it doesn't exist, I want to see if item 1('a') exists in the other list. Neither of my two examples below work because the index is out of range when only 1 item exists.

```
varList = ['a', 'b']

#example 1:
activeList = varList[1] if varList[1] else varList[0]

#example 2:
if varList[1]:
    activeList = varList[1]
else:
    activeList = varList[0]


#I have been temporarily using the following, as I only have two items 
if len(varList) == 2:
    activeList = varList[1]
else:
    activeList = varList[0]

#However should the list size ever change to include more items this will not work
```

Comment: If you always need the last element, you could just do `activeList = varList[-1]`, no?

Comment: It's rather confusing what you mean by "see if it exists in another list". Is this relevant at all? It doesn't seem like it. And what do you want to do if your list ever contains more than two items? Still get the second or first item? Or always get *the last* item? Can your logic be expressed any simpler, like "get the last item"?

Comment: Proposal to *get the last of possibly two items:* `varList[:2][-1]` — always works as long as there's at least one item.

Comment: When I said "see if it exists in another list" I meant that I needed it to keep it's value, and not get treated as a Boolean since originally this was an 'or' statement, sorry if that made it confusing. I think negative indexing is a good solution for now, thank you both!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use try-except. This attempts what is in the try statement and has two possible outcomes:

1. The try statement works and the except statement is ignored.
2. The try statement fails and is ignored, the except statement is executed instead.

```
try:
    activeList = varList[1]
except:
    activeList = varList[0]
```